# Remove blocking script by detecting if Dom is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I [follow the article](http://www.techumber.com/2014/05/simple-non-blocking-javascript-mulitple-scripts.html) about how to remove blocking script by detecting if the dom is ready.

```
  // Check if dom is ready
  function DOMReady(callback) {
    if (document.addEventListener) { // native event
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback, false);
    } else if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('load', callback, false);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', callback);
    }
  }
```

then inside body, I can call

```
<script>
    DOMReady(function () {
        loadJS(['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'
        ], function () {               
            //alert("All Scripts Loaded");
        })
    });
 $(document).ready(function (e) { alert($('.abc').text()); })
</script>
<div class="abc">safdsfsd</div>
```

It just doesn't work, is there anything wrong with these code. Please help.

The [full code is here at plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oChZnGEKBiZGJ610lRIc?p=preview)

Comment: @wZVanG: you can open the plnker or the article to view it. It's too long to put here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you're trying to use `$(document).ready()` BEFORE jQuery has loaded.

When you switched jQuery to dynamic (non-blocking) loading, that means you have to wait for it to load before you attempted to use it.

Of course, your `DOMReady()` function is already doing the work of `$(document).ready()` so you can just use it for that instead of just put the code you would have put inside `$(document).ready()` in the callback that comes back from loading jQuery.  At that point in your code you know that the DOM is ready and jQuery is loaded so it's OK to use jQuery to modify the DOM.

---

In addition, you don't have to wait for the DOM to be ready in order to load jQuery asynchronously so it won't block the page.

You could just do this:

```
<script>
    loadJS(['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'
        ], function () {               
            $(document).ready(function (e) { alert($('.abc').text()); });
        })
    });

</script>
<div class="abc">safdsfsd</div>
```

This will load jQuery asynchronously (non-blocking) and then when it is loaded, it will set up your `$(document).ready()` code.

---

Also, you obviously have to make sure that `loadJS()` is already loaded since it isn't a built-in function.

Comment: sorry, i should put all my jquery calls like  DOMReady(function () {
        loadJS(['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'
        ], function () {               
          jquery calls ? is that right?
        })

Comment: thanks for your help. I'll mark the best answer when Stackoverflow allows me :)